# Error when configuring database settings when setting up moodle 3.2.8+

Tags: mysql, innodb, moodle, barracuda

I was installing moodle on an ubuntu server. I tried following the steps given in their documentation https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu

but, after I set the innodb file format to Barracuda in the mysqld.cnf file by adding the line

```
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
```

I can't restart the MySQL server. It gives me the error message

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I tried to restart the server without setting the file type, it restarted but when setting up database from the web interface, I get the error message

```
mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/moodle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 79
```

Comment: Your question could be more specific. Perhaps "Issue configuring MySQL server for Barracuda InnoDB format" would help. The Moodle 3.2.8 bit should be part of the details as you have them, but isn't pertinent to someone looking through a list of questions asked.

Comment: I have this same problem. It turns out by default mysql 8 has these options by default, but removes the variable, so when moodle checks the variable it thinks it is not set this way. Its a bug in moodle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what MySQL version you were using, but Barracuda is the default `innodb_file_format` value since MySQL 5.7, so most likely that configuration is not necessary.

Also, to find out why the database service is not starting, you should send the MySQL log file, and if the application is not working you should send the application log file or apache log file to have more information about the issue.